# Make a Second Row Menu Mutable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an app, and I will need to fetch information about different entities from my database. So i have different entities in different tables, but they have some fields in common.

I wish to do something similar:

-> Will be presented a bar with several combo boxes of common attributes from different entities, and one of these will be a box where you can choose a type.

Once you choose a type, a second bar would appear below the first, with only fields related with that particular entity.

My doubt is how to make it on the xml, since I need to fill it up, and how I could approach this programmatically.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try something

Comment: Not yet, I'm actually looking for suggestions.